# Adding code to a NLTK sentence?

Tags: python, nltk

Id like to add a piece of my code in the middle of a NLTK sentence, though i dont know how to properly do it, ive tried almost everything.
My current code gives me a syntax error like this:

```
url = raw_input("input")
    ^ syntax error
```

code:

```
pairs =(
        (r'Who are you',
        ("I am an AI programmed to respond to your questions",
        "I am a python script")),

        (r'Can you open a webpage for me?',
url = raw_input('Enter URL: ')
req = Request(url)
try:
    response = urlopen(req)
except URLError, e:
    if hasattr(e, "reason"):
        print "We failed to reach a server."
        print 'Reason: ', e.reason
    elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
        print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
        print 'Error code: ', e.code
else:
    print 'URL is good!'
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

heres the part of the code thats confusing, i dont really get how im supposed to code this, and if its possible at all?

Thank you for your time

Python 2.7

Comment: Post text not a link to your code, you have a syntax error on the previous line you've already closed the braces here: `pairs =(
        (r'Who are you',
        ("I am an AI programmed to respond to your questions",
        "I am a python script")),<-------
 
        (r'Can you open a webpage for me?',` change to:`pairs =(
        (r'Who are you',
        ("I am an AI programmed to respond to your questions",
        "I am a python script",
 
       r'Can you open a webpage for me?')`

Comment: Actually it looks like you've failed to provide the other half of the pair on the previous line: `(r'Can you open a webpage for me?',` you need to balance the parentheses at the very least: `(r'Can you open a webpage for me?',)`

Comment: Im sorry, there is more code at the other side, thats why the parantheses dont add up

Comment: Well without fixing that you will get your current syntax error

Comment: It does add up eventually, but i cant put the code in the middle of the pairs, i had to turn it into a function and then call it there, though im getting a typeerror now

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the best choice is to change the way you're handling the data. Those pairs (I guess) are meant to contain possible answers, while that code would be an action, not an actual answer. So in my opinion you should keep a more consistent philosophy and adopt for example this solution:
in a pair, the first item is the question (so far so good) and the second the name of a function which when called will answer that question.

```
def openurl():
    url = raw_input()
    ...

("...?", openurl)
```